# Why does the vscode golang plugin remove spaces around operators on save?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

If it matters, I've been writing code for many years, but I'm only now exploring golang and vscode at the same time.

On my Linux box, I installed vscode (1.56.2) and the golang plugin (0.25.1).

I've been stepping through some simple golang tutorials, and I noticed a curious thing that happened when I saved a file I had edited.

This is the line I had:

```
out = append(out, base + v)
```

When I saved it, it went to this:

```
out = append(out, base+v)
```

It removed the spaces around the "+" operator.  I went searching through the vscode and golang extension settings, and I found almost nothing about what it will do on save.

In fact, in Settings, I have "Format On Save" UNchecked.

So, what is doing this, and why?  Do I have any ability to configure this?

Comment: The standard style of Go is whatever `go fmt` produces.

Comment: see https://blog.golang.org/gofmt

Comment: Ok, both of those comments didn't actually answer most of my explicit and implicit questions.  I also read that document that talks about gofmt, and I can't find anything that actually describes what the formatting rules are.

Comment: I even set "editor.formatOnSave" to false in a "[go]" block in "settings.json", and it still does this conversion.

Comment: This seems like a VSCode bug, if you can’t disable formatting. While there might be a VSCode problem here, every other Go programmer is going to expect the code to be properly formatted, so there’s little point to the exercise.

Comment: It makes no sense to not allow spaces around operators.  I and our team are very multilingual, and no language formatting guidelines that I've ever used specified that. It makes no sense to use different formatting standards for arithmetic expressions, especially one that is effectively hard to read.

Comment: To quote Rob Pike, “Gofmt's style is nobody's favourite, but gofmt is everybody's favourite."  The point of the tooling is to remove any pointless debates about formatting style, and just make code uniform.

Answer (score 5):

> So, what is doing this, and why?

Your editor runs the the `gofmt` command on save. The command uses space to show operator precedence.

The following snippet is formatted with the `gofmt` command. Notice how operands are closer to the higher precedence operators.

```
fmt.Println(a + b + c + d)
fmt.Println(a * b * c * d)
fmt.Println(a + b*c + d)
fmt.Println(a*b + c*d)
```

The `gofmt` command removes the spaces around the `+` in the question because the `+` has precedence over the `,`.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with VScode. If you have this file:

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main() {
   var a []int
   a = append(a, 1 + 2)
   fmt.Println(a)
}
```

Running `gofmt file.go` gives you:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
        var a []int
        a = append(a, 1+2)
        fmt.Println(a)
}
```

Comment: Ok, and where in vscode can you turn off the formatter, as I already have "Format on Save" UNchecked?  And where can I get information on what formatting rules gofmt implements?

Comment: @DavidM.Karr those are different questions - perhaps you can make new posts